# How to keep the current image in slideshow still the same when refresh a webpage?

Tags: javascript

On my website (http://daaamnthisisfunny.blogspot.com/) I have set up an image slide show that every time the user clicks the right arrow it will take him/her to the next picture, and do the opposite when clicks the previous arrow. The problem is when the user refresh the page it will reset the slide to the first image. What I want to make is a website like (http://9gag.com/gag/1672046) that every time the user click on the next arrow the Url of the site will change accordingly. Do you have any ideas how I can accomplish that ?

This is what i am using for my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript">

            var NumberOfImages = 10
            var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

            img[0] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg"
            img[1] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/2.jpg"
            img[2] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/3.jpg"
            img[3] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/4.jpg"
            img[4] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/5.jpg"
            img[5] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/6.jpg"
            img[6] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/7.jpg"
            img[7] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/8.jpg"
            img[8] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/9.jpg"
            img[9] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/10.jpg"

            var imgNumber = 0
            function NextImage()
            {
                imgNumber++
                if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages)
                    imgNumber = 0
                document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
            }
            function PreviousImage()
            {
                imgNumber--
                if (imgNumber < 0)
                    imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1
                document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
            }


</script>



<body>
<center>

<img name="VCRImage" src="http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg" /></dr>
<br />
<a href="javascript:PreviousImage()">
<img border="0" src="left1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:NextImage()">
<img border="0" src="right1.jpg" /></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save the current image number in the cookie. so as soon as the page loads you check for the presence of a cookie first. If there is one then you set the current image to the number in the cookie.

By the way this is all done in javascript.

Example.

```
var imgNumber = getCookie("lastImage") || 0; 
// where getCookie is a function to retrieve cookie value
```

**Update:**

here are 2 hand functions:

```
// get Cookie
function getCookie(szName){
    var szValue = null,
    cookie = document.cookie,
    arr.arr2;
    if (cookie){ // only if cookie exists
        arr = cookie.split((escape(szName) + '='));
        if(2 <= arr.length){
        arr2 = arr[1].split(';');
        szValue = unescape(arr2[0]);
        }
    }
    return szValue;
}

// set Cookie
function setCookie(szName, szValue, szExpires, szPath, szDomain, bSecure) {
    var szCookieText = escape(szName) + '=' + escape(szValue),
    date;
    if(!szExpires) // default expiration date : 1 year
    {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(365*24*60*60*1000));
        szExpires = date.toGMTString();
    }

    szCookieText += (szExpires ? '; EXPIRES=' + szExpires : '');
    szCookieText += (szPath ? '; PATH=' + szPath : '');
    szCookieText += (szDomain ? '; DOMAIN=' + szDomain : '');
    szCookieText += (bSecure ? '; SECURE' : '');
    document.cookie = szCookieText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, how about on page unload set a cookie value? May work but I'd have to test
I'd recommend using jquery for events:
http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Then for cookie parsing use
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

I'm not positive this will work

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use HTML5's [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) method. This allows you to change the URL that is used to reload the page. This depends on the server sending the correct image in the slideshow for the given URL. Although the next and previous links would appear to link to those same URLs, you would actually call replaceState behind the scenes to avoid reloading the page.

For browsers that don't support replaceState you can still change the anchor of the URL. For browsers that support the `:target` CSS pseudoclass the slideshow can be written entirely in CSS. Otherwise you will need to show the correct image depending on the anchor. Some browsers provide the hashchange event which allows you to detect the user changing the anchor (e.g. by clicking back).